# Remote Handshake exception occuring from service layer

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, exception, javax

When I am trying to execute this part of code

```
public String GetWebSite(String URL) {
        try {
            URL myUrl = new URL(URL);
            URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader( connection.getInputStream() ));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line;
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(line); input.close();

            return sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

It's throwing this exception:

```
ssl peer shutdown incorrectly because of remote handshake exception
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:946) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:275) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:254) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:123) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:318) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at com.innodata.bsi.service.impl.CrossRefDoiService.uploadDoiToCrossRef(CrossRefDoiService.java:72) ~[CrossRefDoiService.class:?]
    at com.innodata.bsi.service.impl.CrossRefDoiService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$31c97d98.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:700) ~[spring-aop-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) ~[spring-aop-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80) ~[spring-aop-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.innodata.bsi.interceptors.MethodLoggingAspect.logTimeMethod(MethodLoggingAspect.java:56) ~[MethodLoggingAspect.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621) [spring-aop-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610) [spring-aop-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65) ~[spring-aop-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:55) [spring-aop-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91) [spring-aop-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:633) [spring-aop-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.innodata.bsi.service.impl.CrossRefDoiService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7cea208b.uploadDoiToCrossRef(<generated>) [spring-core-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at com.innodata.bsi.consumer.DDDoiRunConsumer.runDD(DDDoiRunConsumer.java:129) [DDDoiRunConsumer.class:?]
    at com.innodata.bsi.consumer.DDDoiRunConsumer.processRunDDMessage(DDDoiRunConsumer.java:98) [DDDoiRunConsumer.class:?]
    at com.innodata.bsi.consumer.DDDoiRunConsumer.handleMessage(DDDoiRunConsumer.java:72) [DDDoiRunConsumer.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:269) [spring-core-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(MessageListenerAdapter.java:463) [spring-jms-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:355) [spring-jms-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:537) [spring-jms-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:497) [spring-jms-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:468) [spring-jms-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325) [spring-jms-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263) [spring-jms-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1101) [spring-jms-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1093) [spring-jms-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:990) [spring-jms-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [?:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:482) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    ... 55 more
```

This is the error while connecting a https web url :[image]

Comment: Hi Shivom, I tried the exact code you have given but not getting any Exception. I gave your stackovreflow post's URL for testing and got HTML code of this page. Can you try again by giving any other Https URL?

Comment: It's working for all other url

Answer (score 0):

Try using HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)myUrl.openConnection();

Comment: thanks for answering it's still showing after using the above line of code.Remote host closed connection during handshake

Comment: Assuming you are using Java 8, please try downloading below jar from the link **http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html** and add to {JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/security.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by updating in java version 1.8.Could any one stillhelp me why the issue with java 1.7 ?How the same part of code is working with java 1.8?It's not recommendable action to solve out this issue please suggest me out.I have also tried to install trusted SSL certificate in my jvm keystore /jre/lib/security/cacerts .After installing certificate still the exception is not solve.